# ansible jinja or python; calculation on a dynamic json structure

Tags: python, json, ansible, jinja2

I am working on ansible 2.5, python 2.7.
I have to execute a calculation on a dynamic json variable.
The variable is dynamic; it can contain from 1 to 1000 objects:
example:

> ```
> var: [
>     {   "name": "object1",
>         "value": 1,
>         "oper": 2
>     },
>     {   "name": "objectN",
>         "value": 40,
>         "oper": 8
>     }
>  ]
> ```

The operation I have to execute is quite basic:
result = (var.object_1.value * var.object_1.oper) + (var.object_2.value * var.object_2.oper) + (var.object_N.value * var.object_N.oper) ...
How to deal with this operation? Is there a jinja function the work with json structure or do I have to create a custom "ansible filter" to work with python functions? 
Thanks all for your advises!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use a loop (you need [Jinja2 2.10 for assignments](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#assignments) to work):

```
- set_fact:
    my_sum: "{% set ns = namespace(sum=0) %}{% for e in var %}{% set ns.sum = ns.sum + e.value * e.oper %}{% endfor %}{{ ns.sum }}"
```